# Make Full Page Scrollbars Control Table with Sticky Headers (CSS Only)

Tags: css, html-table, material-ui, sticky

The following sandbox shows code that works perfectly well for a Material UI `Table` placed within a `Paper` component with a sticky header: https://codesandbox.io/s/2n40y

I would like the scrollbars (horizontal and vertical) to appear at the edges of the browser page, bottom and right respectively, yet still control the scrolling of the `Table` itself.

Currently I am only able to do this when removing the table from the Paper and making it a child of the page directly -- or a child of a main `div` that would span the full page height. Yet I need the `Paper` component to remain there, where other components will be placed above and below it.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

UPDATE: in the attached sketch, the browser border appears in black and the scrollbars where they should ideally be appear in green. There is a container div in the middle of the page that contains the table in red. The table's headers should be sticky and the table shouldn't appear beyond the container div which acts as an aesthetic wrapper around it. Ideally, the browser vertical scrollbar would scroll the whole page down while leaving the page header (title + subtitle) and the table headers sticky. Also, when horizontally scrolling, the table should scroll within the container div. This is why I marked the parts that should not ideally appear in dashed lines.

[image]

Comment: Remove `style={{ height: "400px" }}` demo.js and it will have full height. If this is not an issue can you explain it better?

Comment: Thank you @VeselinKontić -- but no, if I do this: (1) the sticky header doesn't stick anymore; and (2) the horizontal scroll is still really within the `Paper` object and not on the bottom of the page, full width. I hope it's clearer?

Answer (score 2):

All the changes we need to make are on `demo.js`

Firstly, we need to use a custom MUI `TableContainer` as the `containerComponent` for your `@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui` `Table`. Basically, the purpose of this is so we can remove the `overflow` properties of the `Table` so that the scrolling is primarily for the body to address the requirement of

> the scrollbars (horizontal and vertical) to appear at the edges of the
> browser page, bottom and right respectively

```
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import makeStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  tableContainer: {
    overflow: "initial"
  }
});

const MUITableContainer = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <TableContainer classes={{ root: classes.tableContainer }} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </TableContainer>
  );
};
```

Secondly, at your `MUITableContainer`, get rid of the `height: 400px` so that the table's height will respond to the content. Again, the browser body bottom & right scrollbars will now control the document's scroll positions - this includes the table. Take a look at the `Table` `containerComponent` prop as well - we have assigned the custom TableContainer we created earlier.

```
<Paper>
  <Grid rows={rows} columns={columns} rootComponent={GridRoot}>
    <Table
      containerComponent={MUITableContainer}
      tableComponent={StickyTable}
    />
    ...
```

Lastly, to test this requirement:

> there will be other objects before and after it.

Just render sample components before & after the `Paper` component

[image: Edit Table Sticky Header (forked)]

Comment: Thank you!! Yes, this is _almost_ it!! The only thing that I'm still unable to make work is that when the screen shrinks, the table gushes out of the `Paper` component. Even though the horizontal scrolling works correctly and is at the bottom of the page, the whole page scrolls instead of the table inside the `Paper`. I hope you see what I mean?

Comment: Take a look at this sample I've written: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-meitner-gc1ye?file=/index.html. Pay attention to the `<script>` at the bottom and my usage of `transform: translateX`

Comment: Ah alright, thank you. So you're saying this can never be done using CSS only?

Comment: I am not at liberty to say that anything can't be done using CSS. Take a look at this for inspiration: https://diana-adrianne.com/purecss-francine/ - this painting is done in pure CSS. But my solution is in fact 1 way to do it and is pretty simple and straight forward for this requirement

Comment: Thank you, I hope at least that my question is well explained!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see the design spec you have referenced, but going off [the sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-meitner-gc1ye?file=/index.html) in the [comment on the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64079439/make-full-page-scrollbars-control-table-with-sticky-headers-css-only#comment113408671_64128510), I think you are trying to keep the header and footer from going off the left edge of the viewport when the user scrolls. But using just CSS, no JavaScript.

I took the entirety of the HTML (only the HTML) from your original code at https://codesandbox.io/s/2n40y (specifically `<div id="root">`) and dropped that into a Codepen.

Then I added a few visual design styles from your example so it looks kinda close.

Then I added the following CSS to make the column headers sticky:

```
th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

I dropped in the following HTML as the first child and last child of `<div id="root">`, though it really doesn't matter where they live as long as they are not *in* the table.

```
  <div class="stuckHeaderFooter">
    [...]
  </div>
```

To keep those from scrolling off screen when I scroll to the right, I made them sticky to the left (for RTL content you would need to make it sticky to the right):

```
.stuckHeaderFooter {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The `padding` just makes it look less ugly. The `inline-block` is there to keep the block-level elements from filling the entire document width, which would keep them from being properly sticky since they would be wider than the viewport. You will probably have to set a `max-width` using `vw` units, but without knowing your content, target sizes, etc., I cannot say what would be best.

Finally, you have to remove the inline `height: 400px` on the first `<div>` under the root (`<div class="MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation1 MuiPaper-rounded" style="height: 400px;">`). If you cannot override it because something injects it, then this style will override it for you but it brittle without knowing what else may be going on:

```
#root > div {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

CSS only, no JavaScript in this approach at all, which is what I think you wanted.

- Pen: https://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/PoNMopM
- Debug view: https://cdpn.io/aardrian/debug/PoNMopM

*Update: 5 October 2020*: Looking at the sketch provided with the question, it is important to note that the container that does the clipping is the one that gets the scrollbar. So your options for a CSS-only solution are limited:

- Add a fake block to  make a visible border on the right (I updated the pen to add one; look at `#root::after` for an example but you will still need JS to make sure that does not appear until the table starts to get covered).
- Yeah, I ran out of ideas.

In conclusion, I don't believe there is a CSS-only solution here because of how clipped areas work.

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting. Unfortunately it's not exactly what I'm after :-(   I must really be bad at explaining, I'm very sorry. Basically, if I can have this: https://2tm7l.csb.app/ but when the table is wide, the horizontal scrolling happens within the paper instead of the table overflowing from outside it, then that works.

Comment: @Sammy can you provide a screen shot of what you want? All I can glean from your descriptions is that you want the regular page scrollbars to handle the table scrolling, but the parts that do not move have to live within an arbitrary node. The demos you keep pasting give me no insight into browser, viewport size, etc. and I think we may all be struggling without a picture (not a web page) of what you want.

Comment: Thanks for following up @aardrian, I will update the question with the screenshot now.

Comment: @Sammy As you have described it no, you cannot do that with CSS alone. The container that does the clipping is the one that gets the scrollbars. In your examples the container doing the clipping does not. I updated the pen to show a fake approach (look at `#root::after`) but it likely a terrible approach.

Comment: I will check it out, thank you. May I ask why you would say "it's a terrible approach"?

Comment: One final thing: is it possible to at least have the vertical scrollbar at the edge of the page itself, but the horizontal bar inside the container clipping the table? I'm able to do this, yet never make the table header stick at the same time.

Comment: @Sammy "terrible" because you cannot easily demonstrate to a user that the table is clipped and scrolling is needed. No way to do a border, a shadow, etc. And if the width the  generated edge is wrong it can clip text even before a scrollbar appears.

Comment: @Sammy yes, you can have a horizontal scrollbar in the container clipping the table (since it does the clipping) _and_ have the page with its own scrollbar. You can see this in action in the embedded pen here: https://adrianroselli.com/2020/01/fixed-table-headers.html#Example

Comment: Sorry Adrien, I meant: have a horizontal scrollbar in the container clipping the table and have the page scrollbar act on the table inside the container, effectively scrolling it vertically.

Comment: @Sammy No. For the same reason.

Comment: Oh well, at least now I know why I was never able to make it work loool -- thanks again for all your time, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the height and width to be equal to the viewport:

```js
<Paper style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}>
```

Example modified: https://codesandbox.io/s/table-sticky-header-forked-l77is?file=/demo.js

Comment: Thank you but no, that's not what I'm after. The `Paper` object must stay in the middle, not take the full screen, as per the design specs.